# Using python, Is it possible to directly send form data to a website server and receive response without using a browser?

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize

I took a programming class in python so I know the basics of the language. A project I'm currently attempting involves submiting a form repeatedly untill the request is successful. In order to achieve a faster success using the program, I thought cutting the browser out of the program by directly sending and recieving data from the server would be faster. Also the website I'm creating the program for has a tendency to crash but I'm pretty sure i could still receive and send response to the server. Currently, im just researching different resources I could use to complete the task. I understand mechanize is easy to fill forms and submit them, but it requires a browser. So my question is what would be the best resource to use within python to communicate directly with the server without a browser.

I apologize if any of my knowledge is flawed. I did take the class but I'm still relatively new to the language.

Comment: If you want to improve your questions' quality here's a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plenty of ways to do this, but the easiest is the third party library called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

With that installed, you can do for example:

```
requests.post("https://mywebsite/path", {"key: "value"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I see from your tags that you've already decided to use requests.

Here's how to perform a basic POST request using requests:

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML
>   form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument. Your
>   dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request
>   is made

```
import requests

payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

response = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

I took this example from [requests official documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

I suggest you to read it and try also other examples available in order to become more confident and decide what approach suits your task best.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post' # Set destination URL here
post_fields = {'foo': 'bar'}     # Set POST fields here

request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
print(json)
```